# Unable to process request due to missing initial state in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, twitter-oauth

I am developing a flutter app i using twitter authentication when i run my app on web it worked. But when I run app on mobile it gives an error.

> Unable to process request due to missing initial state. This may happen if browser storage is inaccessible or accidentally deleted.

I remove all my browser history. Clear all cookies. Allow all cookies. Try on different mobile devices.

[image: This is the error]

NOTE: the app worked on chrome, but not on mobile.

Comment: Tnx for improve my question